# Linq to objects and lambda expression

Tags: c#

There are classes Client and Commande :

```
public class Client {
    public int Identifiant { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Commande
{
    public int Identifiant {get; set;}
    public int IdentifiantClient {get;set;}
    public decimal Prix {get;set;}
}
```

Here are some lists based on these classes :

```
List<Client> listeClients = new List<Client>
{   new Client{Identifiant=1,Nom="Nicolas",Age=30},
    new Client{ Identifiant = 2, Nom = "Jérémie", Age = 20},
    new Client{ Identifiant=3, Nom="Delphine", Age=30},
    new Client{Identifiant = 4, Nom = "Bob", Age = 10}
};

List<Commande> listeCommandes = new List <Commande>
{
    new Commande{Identifiant=1, IdentifiantClient=1, Prix = 150.05M},
    new Commande{Identifiant=2, IdentifiantClient= 2, Prix= 30M},
    new Commande{Identifiant= 3, IdentifiantClient= 1, Prix= 99.99M},
    new Commande{Identifiant= 4, IdentifiantClient= 1, Prix= 100M},
    new Commande{Identifiant= 5, IdentifiantClient = 3, Prix = 80M},
    new Commande{Identifiant = 6, IdentifiantClient = 3,Prix = 10M}
};
```

Now there is this Linq expression :

```
var liste = from commande in listeCommandes
            join
            client in listeClients on commande.IdentifiantClient equals client.Identifiant
            group commande by new {commande.IdentifiantClient, client.Nom}
            into commandesGroupees
            let total = commandesGroupees.Sum(c => c.Prix)
            where total > 50
            orderby total 
            select new {
                commandesGroupees.Key.IdentifiantClient, 
                commandesGroupees.Key.Nom, 
                NombreDeCommandes = commandesGroupees.Count(),
                PrixTotal = total
            };

foreach(var element in liste)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Le client {0} ({1}) a réalisé {2} commande(s) pour un total de {3}", element.Nom, element.IdentifiantClient, element.NombreDeCommandes, element.PrixTotal);
}
```

In the Linq expression there is this expression : `let total = commandesGroupees.Sum(c => c.Prix)` . How is it possible that the parameter c represents an instanciation of the Command class ? because there is the calling of the property `Prix` !

Comment: I dont understand why the object is an instance of the class Commande.

Comment: Are you asking how lambda works, or asking why it's that and not something else?

Comment: I am asking why it is that and not something else ( the class Client instance for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyse this query expression bit by bit.

```
from commande in listeCommandes
```

It is clear that if `listeCommandes` is a `List<Commande>`, `commande` should be of type `Commande`. Right?

```
join
client in listeClients on commande.IdentifiantClient equals client.Identifiant
```

This join joins the client list to the query. Now we have a `client` variable of type `Client`. But this doesn't have much to do with `commande`, which is still of type `Commande`.

```
group commande by new {commande.IdentifiantClient, client.Nom}
into commandesGroupees
```

This is where it gets interesting. When you group `commande`, a bunch of `IGrouping<AnonymousClass, Commande>` are created. This is exactly the `commandesGroupees` here.

So what happens if you call `Sum` on a `IGrouping<AnonymousClass, Commande>`? Remember that `Sum` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, and `IGrouping<AnonymousClass, Commande>` implements `IEnumerable<Commandes>`. This means that you are basically calling `Sum` on a `IEnumerable<Commandes>`, which expects a `Function<Commande, decimal>`.

Comment: So the first variable in the query gets the priority of the instance ?

Comment: @pheromix Joining doesn't change the objects you're iterating over (`listeCommandes`), and you are still grouping objects from `listeCommandes`, you're simply choosing a key to group by: `new {commande.IdentifiantClient, client.Nom}`. The result of the grouping should be a `IGrouping<anonymousType, Commande>`

Comment: @pheromix In the case of group by, yes. Instead of thinking about first variable and second variable, think about this logically. I ask you to group a bunch of blocks by their color, and you will produce a bunch of groups, each of which has a bunch of blocks in it and the blocks in each group all have the same color, right? That's an `IGrouping<Color, Block>`. Now imagine I ask you to group the blocks by X. You will end up with a bunch of `IGrouping<X, Block>`. Make sense?

Comment: @pheromix Notice how whatever X is, the second argument of `IGrouping` is always `Block`, because you are grouping blocks. X is just a criteria you group by. The groups won't end up containing something else just because X is something else.

Comment: @pheromix For the reasons explained by Sweeper and myself? `from commande in listeCommandes` gives you an `IEnumerable<Commande>`. Joining data from somewhere else, or grouping those commands by another value isn't going to magically change them into a different object type.

Comment: @pheromix In words, your code is saying this: group the `commandes` by both the `IdentifiantClient` and the `Nom` of the client who is joined to that `commande`.

Comment: So is it the variable after the `group` keyword which tells the type of the instance in the lambda expression ?

Comment: @pheromix Yes. That's what I said in the first sentence of my first comment.

Answer (score 2):

Let's chunk it in smaller bits to make it simpler

```
from commande in listeCommandes
```

commande is of type Commande

```
group commande by new { commande.IdentifiantClient, client.Nom }
```

This is probably the bit confusing you, this still creates an IEnumerable<Commande> not an IEnumerable<anonymous<identifiantclient,nom>>, the new is what you want to group by, not what you want the grouped items to be, at this point you're creating an IGrouping that has IdentifiantClient and Nom as key but has an IEnumerable has an element

```
into commandesGroupees
```

Gives a name to the IGrouping we previously created

```
let total = commandesGroupees.Sum(c => c.Prix)
```

An IGrouping<TKey,TValue> is an IEnumerable<TValue> so as we've seen earlier each of the groups (grouped by idenfiantClient and Nom) hold a sequence of commands, since we're doing a linq query on it (sum) we're not concerned about the key but about the IEnumerable that is exposed (the IEnumerable<Command>).

This is why the sum works on Command and those have a Prix property.

Comment: I am not still convinced.

Comment: @pheromix You'll have to explain what isn't clear, that's just exactly how this works so if you don't get it you need to tell me which part isn't clear so i can better elaborate.

Comment: why is it not based on the Client class ?

Comment: @pheromix, tu as `group commande`, le groupe est donc un group de Commande. `group client` donnera un groupe de Client

Comment: So the `group` keyword tells what is the instance ? but not the variable in the query ?

Comment: @pheromix group says what you group, and by says what the key will be for the group, so group x by y means i want to group all x with the same y together, you still end up with each of those being x, not y